# How i can test my unpublished assistant app using google home device

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I have created a custom Dialogflow assistant app.I am  able to test the same using simulator and google assistant on my mobile but not able to test using google Home device. I don't want to publish the app, but i want to test the same using Google Home device.

I configured the google home device with google Home app on mobile with same developer account but app is not responding.

Can anyone suggest that how i can test my unpublished assistant app using google home device.

Comment: Could you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example so we can help you better.

Comment: If you are able to invoke the App in the AoG smulator, then you should try to access the app in google home device by telling the same invocation phrase.
If you are not able to invoke the app by the invocation phrase, then re-visit the invocation phrase by following documentation here https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/invocation-and-discovery

Answer (score 2):

If the account you use in the simulator and on your mobile device is the same account you used to setup the Home, then you should be able to access it from the Home. If you're not, then you need to provide exactly what error you're getting on the Home device and include some screen shots of the simulator Debug tab so we can see if something obvious is amiss. If you continue to have problems, you'll need to contact Google, since something sounds very wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not able to see any log.If there is any way to see the logs please let me know.

Comment: A description of what is happening on the home or looking at the Stackdriver logs at cloud.console.google.com would be a help on that side. Showing cases where it works on the simulator will help provide contrast. Especially since what you're suggesting shouldn't happen.